# Change screen color balance programmatically

Tags: c#, c++, vb.net, windows, gdi

What is the name of the function in GDI32.DLL to change color balance on Windows?

For example to change device gamma I need to use SetDeviceGammaRamp

```
[DllImport("GDI32.dll")]
private unsafe static extern bool SetDeviceGammaRamp(Int32 hdc, void* ramp);
```

Comment: by color balance you mean brightness and modifying RGB values, right?

Comment: right (red, green and blue), the same values you can modify at "Adjust Color Balance" on dccw.exe

Comment: WcsAssociateColorProfileWithDevice()

Answer (score 0):

You can adjust RGB values of screen and change it's brightness with exactly same function as you mentioned: `SetDeviceGammaRamp`

See here: 
http://www.nirsoft.net/vc/change_screen_brightness.html

Second parameter of function, you're passing RGB values:

```
//Generate the 256-colors array for the specified wBrightness value.
        WORD GammaArray[3][256];

        for (int iIndex = 0; iIndex < 256; iIndex++)
        {
            int iArrayValue = iIndex * (wBrightness + 128);

            if (iArrayValue > 65535)
                iArrayValue = 65535;

            GammaArray[0][iIndex] = 
            GammaArray[1][iIndex] = 
            GammaArray[2][iIndex] = (WORD)iArrayValue;

        }

        //Set the GammaArray values into the display device context.
        bReturn = SetDeviceGammaRamp(hGammaDC, GammaArray);
```